# Why does %c print '?' and what is its meaning

Tags: c, char, printf, format-string

Two examples

```
printf("\n %c , ((unsigned char)a[i]+100);

printf("\n %c , -11);
```

Returns

```
?
?
```

Comment: It's unlikely that this is a true `?` character.  More likely that it's a character that your terminal is having trouble displaying, or if you are using a graphical terminal then that particular character does not exist in the current font.

Comment: Posting the results of `printf("\n %d" , ((unsigned char)a[i]+100);` would help.

Comment: @chux pardon me if I am asking something basic, but wouldn't `%d` with `(unsigned char)` be wrong? Shouldn't it be `%u`? I always have trouble understanding default arg promotion.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yes, `"%u"` would be better.  Makes no difference if `UCHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX`.

Comment: @chux, but if I understand correctly, the bit representation for `unsigned int` will be passed and it will be reinterpreted as `int`. Are they allowed to have different representations by the standard?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya When the value is representable in both the signed and unsigned version, either specifier is OK.  See C11 §6.5.2.2 6

Comment: @chux perfect! Thanks. Does this automatically imply that signed and unsigned integers should use the same representation (at least for the value in the common range)?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing " in both statements.  What compiler are you using?  If you compile with gcc with the -Wall compiler flag on you would see:

```
warning: missing terminating " character
     printf("\n %c , ((unsigned char)a[i]+100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Character -11 is not a valid 7-bit ASCII character. It's also an invalid UTF-8 byte, hence the `?` result.

Only characters 0-127 are valid for `%c`. Everything else is going to be part of a multi-byte UTF-8 character, or is character-set dependent.

Comment: "Only characters 0-127 are valid for %c ..." --> Disagree. Any 0 or positive value passed as an `int` is OK --> "the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written."  `printf("\n %c , 'X' + 256);` and `printf("\n %c ,  255);`  are fine.

Answer (score 1):

`"%c"` expects an `int`.

`(unsigned char)a[i]+100`  is a `(unsigned char) + (int)`.  When `(unsigned char)` is 8-bit (most common), this results in an `int`.  Thus, in both of the below, code pass an `int` to `printf()`.

```
printf("\n %c , ((unsigned char)a[i]+100);
printf("\n %c , -11);
```

`"%c"` converts that `int` to a `unsigned char`.

> `c` ... the `int` argument is converted to an
>   `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written.  C11dr §7.21.6.1 8

Assuming an 8-bit `unsigned char`, that converted value is in the range 0 to 255.  -11 becomes 245.  Then the character is written.  For values in the ASCII range of 0-127, we usually see the ASCII character or effect of a control character.  Other values print other things.

Certainly on OP's platform the output defaults to `?` for many of those out-of-ASCII-range characters. [@paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776933/why-does-c-print-and-what-is-its-meaning#comment96333863_54776933)

Answer (score 0):

You guessed it, `c` returns a character. This means that in `%c` a character is substituted at that location within the print string.